# How do I parse this API in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, api, parsing, retrofit

Need help parsing the API

API

{"timestamp": "1579830409",  "bids": [["8361.15", "0.77921260"], ["8359.25", "0.00766313"], ["8359.10", "0.26755828"]], "asks": [["8360.15", "0.77920260"], ["8389.25", "0.00796313"], ["8358.10", "0.26785828"]]}

> In JSONViewer

```
{
 timestamp:"1579830409" 
 []bids
 []asks
  0:"8360.15"
  1:"0.77920260"
}
```

I am unsure how to parse the array inside array part.
Bids/Asks is an array containing arrays with 2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bids/Asks can be `List<List<String>>`. The String can be parsed to Double.